# Application won't open in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I've just started learning Spring and I'm trying to install the proper environment by going through a book I bought ("Developing Enterprise Java Applications with Spring Frameworks") but I'm not having much luck. I've got everything installed and working as far as the tests go: 
- Eclipse (Indigo) 
- Tomcat 7.0.35 
- SQL Server 
- Ant 1.8.4

I've deployed my project and I am now running tomcat. When I open tomcat via my browser and enter manager app, I can see my project and running = true. But when I click on it, I'm getting the "Webpage is not available". I'm not seeing any errors displayed on any of my consoles and since I'm new to this I'm not sure where to start to look for a solution. Let me know what other information you need in order to point me in the right direction. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What does catalina.out say? An error should be logged with default settings. Otherwise you might have to change logging settings

Comment: I'm getting this error: Connector attribute SSLCertificateFile must be defined when using SSL with APR.  I'm looked online at solutions,  commenting out the APR code and using other server.xml files, but I don't fully understand it and none of these solutions are working.